# Modify a css animation property?

Tags: gwt

Is there a way to programatically define and start a css animation? I'd like to animate a div from one absolute position to another. Something like:

```
FlowPanel fp = new FlowPanel();
fp.getElement().getStyle().setPosition(Position.ABSOLUTE);
fp.getElement().getStyle().setLeft(50, Style.Unit.PX);
fp.getElement().getStyle().setTop(50, Style.Unit.PX);

...

// something like:
fp.setAnimation("top: 300px");
```

I saw that we could define a css animation in our css file, and changing the name of the div's style will trigger the animation. But I don't know if we can programatically modify an animation defined in css. For example:

```
// css file
.testAnimation {
  top: 500px;
  transition-property: top;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

...

// But we can't modify the "top" attribute here depending on runtime needs?:
fp.setStyleName("testAnimation"); // I may want "top" to be some other value here.
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249880/how-to-add-css-animationend-event-handler-to-gwt-widget

Comment: Can you update which approach you chose and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several approaches

1) GWT Animation - http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwAnimation

2) Jquery Approach - via GWTQuery - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/6kOSm0HBP4A

3) JSNI In GWT - [How to add CSS AnimationEnd event handler to GWT widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249880/how-to-add-css-animationend-event-handler-to-gwt-widget)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getElement().getStyle().setProperty( property, value )` to set any css property. But this is not the right way of doing it. Suggested way is to do via css.

This [Link](http://blog.francoismaillet.com/?p=68) might help you